# Get current Slide number from BxSlider

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery bxslider.

I want to get currentslidenumber when I click on next, here is my code

```
function slider() {
 $('.recent_articles').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 223,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 8,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 18,
           infiniteLoop: false,
           pager:false,

       });
}


$(document).on('click','.bx-next', function() {
 var total = slider.getCurrentSlide();
 alert(total);
});

slider();
```

Now when I click, I get this error:

> TypeError: slider.getCurrentSlide is not a function

Anybody tells me how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code:

```
var mySider = $('.recent_articles').bxSlider({
                   slideWidth: 223,
                   minSlides: 2,
                   maxSlides: 8,
                   moveSlides: 1,

                   ------
                   ------
               });
```

And, call getCurrentSlide() as:

```
$(document).on('click','.bx-next', function(){
    var total = mySider.getCurrentSlide();
    alert(total);
});
```

Comment: Issue wasn't mine.. I posted exact answer few seconds after you.. then I deleted it since you answered it first

Comment: Oh..cool. Anyways it happened accidentally and it's great to see who thinks like me almost in the same way at same time. Chill :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.stepslider').bxSlider({
minSlides: 1,
maxSlides: 1,
moveSlides: 1,
slideWidth: 1280,
slideMargin: 5,
infiniteLoop: false,
auto: false,
hideControlOnEnd: true,
pager: false,
onSlideBefore: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
var gosteps = currentSlideHtmlObject+1; //get current slide index you can add class this is working in mobile touch also
$(".steps-count span").text(gosteps);
console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject+1); //get current slide
}
});
```

using currentSlideHtmlObject element you can get current slide before sliding you have to update currentSlideHtmlObject+1 as current slide.